# How do I pull appscan source filter parameters from the database

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

Using the IBM AppScan SDK I can open an assessment and apply a filter to create a new assessment.  What I would like to do is produce a report that shows the assessment had x findings to start with and after a filter was applied, it now has y findings.  I would like to include on the report the parameters from the filter I applied.

Comment: Please let us know what API/SDK you are using; what URL are you using for documentation; and what commands you are executing to accomplish your current assessment compare.  Can you tell us more about what you
are using for a filter and how you are defining it?

Comment: I'm using the SDK provided with AppScan Source for Analysis.  I'm using the 9.0.1 version.  I create a factory connection, login, openAssessmentFile, Finging [] findings = myAssessment.getFundings(someFilter);

Comment: I'm looking for the details of someFilter to go with the number of findings.